# How to switch between 2019 and 2017 projects in Visual Studio solutions?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to dynamic link the projects in a VS solution? Here my scenerio...

> VS solution
>
> - C++ project (v141, VS2017)
> - C# project (.net 4.8)

If I open the VS solution in VS 2017 it adds the C++ project v141...

> VS solution
>
> - C++ project (v142, VS2019)
> - C# project (.net 4.8)

and if I open the same solution in VS 2019 it adds the C++ project with v142.

Comment: Not sure how VS2017 will handle it but try this: in VS2019, on the C++ project properties, select (in General - Platform Toolset) to use "Visual Studio 2017 (v141)".

Comment: @AdrianMole I have two C++ projects (project_v2017.vcproj and project_v2019.vcproj)... but the solution in VS2017 is not able to load project_v2019.vcproj so it should switch to the existing project_v2017.vcproj

Comment: Not sure that's how it works. VS2019 *can* open the old project, so it likely will, then 'update' it. If it's the same solution file, then it will (attempt to) open the same project(s).

Comment: You can try adding different configurations in the *same* project - one for VS2017 and one for VS2019. Not sure if the two keep different settings/profiles, though.